# UFW block by hostname

Tags: ufw, hostname

Been searching for a while now, but I still can't find a simple answer to my simple problem.

I run an FTP server and for security reasons I want to allow access (port 21) only from

thispartvaries.myoperator.fi and thispartvaries.myoperatormobile.fi

Is there any simple way of doing this with UFW?

Comment: @user535733 That is an answer not a comment. Please consider converting your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not simply. UFW doesn't speak hostname, nor do the inbound packets. Everyone at that party speaks (numeric) IP addresses.

You can see one example at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91701 how others taught IPTables/UFW to resolve hostnames. It's an imperfect solution, since it's certain to have periods when the hostname and IP address are out of sync. The more weffort you make to keep the two synchronized in UFW, the kess simple it gets.